# File mounted as docker volume becomes corrupt when saved outside docker

Tags: macos, file, docker, virtualbox, corrupt

In my host, I have this dir:

`/Users/gezimhome/projects/ziprecipes.net/zip-recipes/src`

which I mount to my docker container as:

`/usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/zip-recipes`

If I modify the following file (e.g. add a new line) outside of docker: 
`/Users/gezimhome/projects/ziprecipes.net/zip-recipes/src/plugins/VisitorRating/scripts/main.js`, I get a syntax error in the browser:

Safari:
[image]

Chrome:
[image]

If I go into the docker container and so much as open the file (`/usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/zip-recipes/plugins/VisitorRating/scripts/main.js`) and **save** it again without changes, the error is gone.

I know this is going to be a mind-bender.

I've tried multiple Editors/IDEs in my host to save the file with. It makes no difference.

**Update**: Wow, I saved the files inside docker both when I edit it from inside docker and when I edit it from outside and did a diff to find no difference:

```
cp /usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/zip-recipes/plugins/VisitorRating/scripts/main.js /host.js
# editted the file in same way inside docker
cp /usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/zip-recipes/plugins/VisitorRating/scripts/main.js /docker.js
root@219a4126d14a:/# diff /host.js /docker.js
root@219a4126d14a:/#
```

Comment: How is this question off-top?! Douche downvote.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this question, I had the exact same issue and it was almost impossible to find a solution. Upvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by `sendfile` setting in nginx.

To fix it, I changed my nginx website config file (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx_wordpress` in my case) to set `sendfile off` as follows:

```
server {
        listen   8080;
        server_name zrdn;

        sendfile off;
        ...
}
```